# Deciding which package manager was used to install a Python package

Tags: python, uninstallation, setuptools, distutils, package-managers

I want to remove a Python package, let's say Satchmo. But I don't remember which tool I used to install it.

I can think of the following ways:

- Downloading source

  - distutils
  - distribute
  - SetupTools
- Python package managers

  - EasyInstall
  - PyPM
  - pip
- apt-get

Is there a way to determine how it was installed? I think I need this information to safely and properly remove them.

Comment: I would love to know this too. If there is not a way to do this, then I think this is a serious must-look-at for the developers of python install tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each installation tool may keep a separate index of which packages it knows about/has installed. All Python cares about is that the files are in place. So basically, if you think it may have been installed with a certain tool, you'll have to ask the tool.

For apt/dpkg, you can check if the package appears in the `dpkg -l` listing. I do not know whether pip's index is as easily accessible, but you could simply try running `pip uninstall package-name`, it should complain if it didn't install the package. I don't know about PyPM, but if you installed from source or with easy_install, you'll simply have to track down and remove the files, the package isn't listed anywhere.